# Install osmosis without wget and still create its folder?

Tags: openstreetmap, ubuntu, osmosis

I am trying to install osmosis onto my Ubuntu 16.04 PC.

I tried to do it using [this explanation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Installation), but I can't download osmosis-latest.tgz because the link throws a 404 error.

Now I installed it by simply using `apt-get install osmosis` which worked well, but I don't know what to do about the osmosis folder which the above explanation creates. I just created an empty folder now, but that's surely not what I would like to have I guess.

PS: As you can tell, I'm new to this.

Comment: osmosis is quite dated, and no longer needed for most tasks. You should look for alternatives such as osmium these days!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need this step when using the package manager. This directory is only created for storing the files from the previously downloaded osmosis archive. Since you already installed osmosis via package manager there is no need to store manually downloaded osmosis files inside this directory.

However, it might be a good idea to use the latest osmosis release. The latest release is available via https://github.com/openstreetmap/osmosis/releases (which is also mentioned on the wiki page). In this case follow the installation guide, including the creation of this directory.

By the way, I updated the wiki page and removed the dead link.

Also keep in mind that osmosis isn't maintained very well. As of today there are better alternatives such as [osmium](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/), as already mentioned by user @mmd.